# list tables from mysql dump file with sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have situation where I need to extract tables list from mysql dump file. I tried that with sed

```
 sed  's/DROP TABLE.*?`(.*?)`/\1/' baza.sql > 1.txt
```

but got this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

what did I miss in my regexp?

Comment: no errors but got a full dump content in 1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Linux, and you need to get all strings inside the first backticks after `DROP TABLE`, I'd suggest using `grep` with a PCRE regex like

```
grep -oP 'DROP TABLE.*?`\K[^`]+' baza.sql > 1.txt
```

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/s848Vc/1).

**Details**

- `DROP TABLE` -  some literal text
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `` ` `` -  a backtick
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `` [^`]+ `` - one or more chars other than a backtick

If you have matches once per line, you may still go with `sed`:

```
sed -nE 's/DROP TABLE.*`([^`]*)`.*/\1/p' baza.sql > 1.txt
```

Here, `-n` suppresses default line output, `-E` enables POSIX ERE (where `(...)` define a capturing group, not `\(...\)`), then `p` flag only prints the result of the substitution.